# Why is it necessary to to use set.find(x) != set.end() while finding an element.

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I am wondering what is wrong when I use `*(set.find(x)) == x`
instead of `set.find(x)!=set.end()`.
It usually works but while attempting a question on Hackerrank (question : [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-sets)).
This code gives CA for all test cases :

```
int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   

set<int>s;
int n,x,y;
cin >> n;
while(n--){
    cin >> y >> x;
    if(y==1)
        s.insert(x);
    else if(y==2)
        s.erase(x);
    else {
        set<int>::iterator it=s.find(x);
        if(it != s.end())
            cout << "Yes" <<endl;
        else cout << "No" <<endl;
    }
}
return 0;}
```

But this doesn't work for 2 test cases. The test case file is too big and it's no use trying to check that huge file. :-

```
 #include <cmath>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <set>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;


 int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

set<int>s;
int n,x,y;
cin >> n;
while(n--){
    cin >> y >> x;
    if(y==1)
        s.insert(x);
    else if(y==2)
        s.erase(x);
    else {
        set<int>::iterator it=s.find(x);
        if(*it==x)
            cout << "Yes" <<endl;
        else cout << "No" <<endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `it == X.end()` then you just cannot dereference it.

Comment: `it != s.end()` implies `*it == x` for `int`s

Comment: Maybe you should use `s.count(c)`.

Comment: @Barry - yes <code>it != s.end()</code> does imply <code>*it == x</code>, however the converse isn't true: if <code>it == s.end()</code>, you can't assume that <code>*it != x</code>, so the two expressions are not equivalent.

Comment: @StephenC.Steel Where do you see me claiming they're equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because if `find` returns the `end` iterator and you dereference it you are triggering undefined behavior, which means that your program may do whatever - happen to work, work incorrectly, plain crash. This is a general rule of all C++ containers - the `end` iterator is just a placeholder for a "one past last" element, used as an end condition for loops or to signal that an element does not exist; you aren't meant to dereference it.

If you want a more compact way to check if an element is present, just use `set.count(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

Test case 10 input

```
19268
3 7401  //first search without any input
```

if the very first input is 3 and for the search of element

```
set<int>::iterator it=s.find(x); //Returns end iterator
```

and when you deference the value of end() it will return exception

```
if(*it==x)
```